# command exection inside find -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c

Tags: shell, find

i was using `find . -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c` to execute series of commands like this

```
find . -type f \
exec grep -q `filter` \
-print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '
sed -i.bak s/this/that/g ${0}
git diff --no-index /path/to/${0}.bak /path/to/${0} >> my.patch
rm ${0}.bak
'
```

this looks like search&replace, backup, patch, remove backup, but when i look at the patch file, most changes are not there, so i tried a different way

```
find . -type f \
exec grep -q `filter` \
-print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak s/this/that/g {} \;
```

after that, i move all `.bak` files to a backup folder, this time, i can see there're many files changed, and patch file generated based on backup and source folder is much bigger

i'm ok with the second approach, i just want to know where i did wrong in first approach, why not all commands were executed inside `sh -c`? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xargs` will try to run the command with as many arguments as it can, but you're only using one of those. Something like the following would process all arguments:

```
xargs -0 sh -c '
for i
do
sed -i.bak s/this/that/g "$i"
git diff --no-index /path/to/"$i".bak /path/to/"$i" >> my.patch
rm "$i".bak
done
' _
```

`for i` (or `for i in "$@"`) will loop over every argument (except `$0`), so it's easier to have something like `_` be `$0` instead and not use `$0` at all.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, your solution works perfectly